# Extra lines written to file using file.write python

Tags: python

I have a list 'test_words' of length 34199 and I wish to write each element of this list into a file 'test_vocab.txt'

This is my code to achieve the same :

```
test_file = open('test_vocab.txt','w')

print(len(test_words))

count = 0

for item in test_words:
    print(count)
    test_file.write("%s\n" % item)
    count=count+1
test_file.close()
```

Now the problem is , even though the list contains only 34199 elements and even when I print out 'count' in each iteration of the loop , it goes only up to 34199 , the actual file contains 35545 lines .

This seems very strange . The loop runs only 34199 times but how does the file contain 35545 lines ? I even closed the file immediately after writing using 'test_file.close()'.

My file should only contain 34199 lines . Can someone please help me resolve this issue ? I don't know how to proceed further

Comment: some of your list elements contain `\n` characters, write the elements surrounded by `@@%s@@\n` and look for lines in file that do not begin with `@@`

Comment: some of the words may contain newline character. you can use `strip()` mehod `test_file.write("%s\n" % item.strip())`

Comment: How is `test_words` created?

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
for x in (test_words):
    test_file.write(x)
```

The reason of you extra lines you´re getting comes from the line break character you are placing. It is not necessary since file.write will add a new line each time it is called, and placing a line break character will result in extra lines added. Try printing a list in a console and check it out. You may want to check one of the good python tutorials available in the web such as the python.org one at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: `file.write will add a new line each time it is called` - I don't believe that this is true

Comment: Well @ snakecharmerb, the extra line its actually add by the for loop, but we are just trying to help @Baharti A to solve his issue.

Answer (score 0):

```py
input_filename = 'input_vocab.txt'
output_filename = 'output_vocab.txt'

with open(input_filename, 'r') as f:
  test_words = f.readlines()

with open(output_filename, 'w') as f:
  for item in test_words:
    f.write(f"{item.strip()}\n")
```